# SQL two tables query

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in a MySQL database. I want to find the count of blood group based on gender using these two tables.

I'm able to get the count gender wise using single table but unable to get it using two table.

```
|-----------------------------------------------------|
|                        DONOR                        |
|-------|-------|----------|--------|------|----------|
|  DID  |  NAME |  GENDER  |  CITY  |  BG  |  AMOUNT  |
|-------|-------|----------|--------|------|----------|
|  1    |  A1   |    F     |  C1    |  AB+ |    7     |
|-------|-------|----------|--------|------|----------|
|  2    |  A2   |    F     |  C2    |  A+  |    2     |
|-------|-------|----------|--------|------|----------|
|  3    |  A3   |    M     |  C1    |  AB+ |    5     |
|-------|-------|----------|--------|------|----------|
|  4    |  A4   |    F     |  C3    |  AB+ |    3     |
|-------|-------|----------|--------|------|----------|
|  5    |  A5   |    M     |  C1    |  A-  |    4     |
|-------|-------|----------|--------|------|----------|
```

```
|-----------------------------------------------------|
|                        ACCEPTOR                     |
|-------|-------|----------|--------|------|----------|
|  AID  |  NAME |  GENDER  |  CITY  |  BG  |  AMOUNT  |
|-------|-------|----------|--------|------|----------|
|  1    |  B1   |    F     |  C1    |  AB+ |    7     |
|-------|-------|----------|--------|------|----------|
|  2    |  B2   |    F     |  C2    |  A-  |    2     |
|-------|-------|----------|--------|------|----------|
|  3    |  B3   |    M     |  C1    |  B+  |    5     |
|-------|-------|----------|--------|------|----------|
|  4    |  B4   |    F     |  C3    |  AB+ |    3     |
|-------|-------|----------|--------|------|----------|
|  5    |  B5   |    M     |  C1    |  A-  |    4     |
|-------|-------|----------|--------|------|----------|
```

OUTPUT

```
F AB+ 4
F A+  1
M AB+ 1
M A-  2
F A-  1
M B+  1
```

Can you please help me with query for this I'm not good with this kind of query.
I have done only single table query.

Comment: Can you explain the logic of the output?

Comment: I just need to find the count of blood group based on gender using two table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need UNION ALL for the 2 tables and aggregation:

```
select t.gender, t.bg, count(*)
from (
  select gender, bg from donor
  union all
  select gender, bg from acceptor
) t
group by t.gender, t.bg
```